# View style is not working in React Native

Tags: react-native

Im new in react native,
before in my code using `const Main = () => { ..}`

but when i change to `export default class Main extends React.Component { ..}` , problems arise like style in View not working but the error `',' expected in style`

Screnshoot :

[image]

im using new version of react native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the render() method where the return() method should be.

Ex:

```
export default class LotsOfStyles extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.red}>just red</Text>
        <Text style={styles.bigBlue}>just bigBlue</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.bigBlue, styles.red]}>bigBlue, then red</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.red, styles.bigBlue]}>red, then bigBlue</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

from [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style)